# Angular: Multiple nested routes

Tags: angularjs, routes, routelink

**Summary**

- I have a list of products situated on a product page (url.com/products)
- When I click on a product i'm presented with a summary and a link to issues with that product (url.com/products/22) - (22 being the product id)
- When i click on the link to view issues, I become stuck.

**What I have so far**

I can display the list of products fine, and I can also display a page once clicking on a product and the URL changes to "url.com/products/10". So that's working fine with the below.

```html
<a [routerLink] = "['/product', product.productID]">
  {{ product.productName }} 
</a>
```

**Question**
Is it possible to use router links to achieve the following?

"url.com/products/10/issues/24"

- Products: The products page which displays a list of products
- 10: The selected product which has an ID of 10
- Issues: A issues list page related to that product
- 24:The selected issue which has an ID of 24

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that in the following way:

- For list of issues: `[routerLink] = "['/product', product.productID, 'issues']"`.
  This will generate a link to `/product/10/issues/`
- For a particular issue: `[routerLink] = "['/product', product.productID, 'issues', issueID]"`.
  This will generate a link to `/product/10/issues/24`

You can get more details over [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink).